# Can't upload multiple large files in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone.js, vue2-dropzone

Curently my code is failing on uploading 9 files each of upto 32MB with following error:
[image]

Also my networks tab shows this request which is of 200 status:
[image]

Here are the dropzone configuration options that I've used:

```
dropzoneOptions: {
    maxFiles: 1000,
    timeout: 100000,
    maxFilesize: 100,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    paramName: 'images',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 100,
    url: `${axios.defaults.baseURL}/admin/album/pictures`,
    headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken()}` },
    error: this.dropzoneSubmissionError,
    success: this.dropzoneSubmissionSuccess,
},
```

Here is the `dropzone` tag:

```
<vue-dropzone
    ref="myVueDropzone" id="dropzone" class="custom-dropzone"
    :options="dropzoneOptions" @vdropzone-sending="addPictures"
    @vdropzone-complete-multiple="vDropzoneCompleteMultiple"
    @vdropzone-total-upload-progress="vDropzoneTotalUploadProgress"
    @vdropzone-canceled="vDropzoneCanceled"
/>
```

And here are the functions that are called by various events mentioned in `dropzone` tag:

```
addPictures(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('album_id', this.$route.params.album_id);
},
vDropzoneCompleteMultiple(response) {
    console.log(response);
},
vDropzoneTotalUploadProgress(progress) {
    this.pictures_uploading = true;
    console.log(progress);
    this.totalUpload.width = progress;
},
vDropzoneCanceled(file) {
    console.log(file);
}
```

Furthermore, since I've logged the total progress in `vDropzoneTotalUploadProgress` function, that progress never exceeds 4.16

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: There is something problem with your vue.js file. either some input needed or code code is missing and if nothings needed then you can try to replace the vue.js file by downloading new one.

Comment: Problem Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!! Actually all I did is this:

```
dropzoneOptions: {
    maxFiles: 1000,
    timeout: 100000,
    maxFilesize: 100,
    paramName: 'images',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 1000,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 100,
    url: `${axios.defaults.baseURL}/admin/album/pictures`,
    headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken()}` },
    error: this.dropzoneSubmissionError,
    successmultiple: this.dropzoneMultipleSubmissionSuccess,
},
```

I just added parallel uploads to my `dropzoneOptions` and set that to maxFiles (you can set that whatever you want but make sure that no matter how many files you add at once, they all get uploaded parallely)

And that's it :) Hope it might help someone